# How do I set a callback in celery

Tags: python, celery

I want to add callback to a function so that when it returns it can call a regular python function,

My Task

```
@celery.task                                                                                                                            
def add(x, y):                                                                                                                         
    return x + y
```

How I want to use it:

```
from __future__ import print_function
delay.add(2, 3 ,callback=lambda x: print x)
```

Instead of the lambda it can be any function that its not defined in the celery tasks
but where the task is called from.

Answer (score 5):

You can only link tasks in this case:

```
add.apply_async((2, 3), link=other_task.s())
```

which is the same as:

```
(add.s(2, 3) | other_task.s())()
```

Waiting for the task to complete makes the task synchronous, so the call you want would
be equivalent to:

```
(lambda x: print(x))(add.delay(2, 3).get())
```

Which would block the current process until the task returns.
If you don't want the process to block then you would have to write
a dedicated thread to wait for results and calling your callbacks.

Or you can use eventlet/gevent and pretty much write normal code.

Comment: Does the callback always have to be defined as a task? Cause if I have a complicated graph, with plenty of dependency nodes that I must declare as tasks, then all my application logic is going to be in tasks.py, which is not ideal...

Comment: I am trying to use callback in my code `send_email.apply_async(
                    args=[json.dumps(payload)],
                    exchange=CELERY_EXCHANGE,
                    routing_key=CELERY_ROUTING_KEY,
                    link=save_email_response.subtask((invite_id, candidate.id, ))
                )` but it's not calling `save_email_response`. I have verified this using `rdb`

Comment: Even tried `(send_email.s(args=[json.dumps(payload)]) | save_email_response.s(invite_id, candidate.id))(exchange=CELERY_EXCHANGE, routing_key=CELERY_ROUTING_KEY)` but did work.